# Creating negative stacking bar chart with Highcharter(Likert chart)

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

The dream is that Jkunst responds, but I am trying to create a negative stacking bar chart with highcharter like the highcharts demo here -http://jsfiddle.net/KV5KV/

I've tried swapping all of the options and what not, but I can't seem to get it to show more than one series at a time, if anybody can help it would be wonderful. Here is what I am trying to run in R.

```
 highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
      hc_title(text = "stuff") %>% 
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = ""), 
               labels = list(format = "{value}"), min=0) %>% 
      hc_plotOptions(column = list( 
        series=list(stacking='normal'),
        dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE), 
        enableMouseTracking = TRUE)) %>% 
      hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
      hc_xAxis(reversed=FALSE,opposite=TRUE,reversed=FALSE, linkedTo=0) %>% 
      hc_series(list(name="Value",color=c("#766A62"),data=list(-10, -5, -6)))    %>%
      hc_add_series(list(name="Value",color=c("#766A62"),data=list(-2, -5, -3)))  %>%
      hc_add_series(list(name="neutral",id='neutral',color=c("#766A62"),data=list(-2, -5, -3)))  %>%
      hc_add_series(list(name="Value",color=c("#766A62"),data=list(5, 1,6)))  %>%
      hc_add_series(list(name="Value",color=c("#766A62"),data=list(2, 5, 3)))  %>%
      hc_add_series(list(linkedTo='neutral',name="neutral",color=c("#766A62"),data=list(6, 8, 2)))
```

Comment: Hi @edge363! Do you have a toy data, or a usual structre of this type of data, we can work on a `hclikert` or something like that!

Comment: First of all you dont use `hc_add_series(list(.. pars...))` you need to use `hc_add_series(..pars...)`. Please, take a look on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/replicating-highcharts-demos.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I HAVE DONE IT.

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Experimental Survey Questions breakdown") %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = ""), 
           labels = list(format = "{value}")) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(series=list(stacking='normal'),column = list( 
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE), 
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(reversed=FALSE,opposite=TRUE,reversed=FALSE) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name="Value",color=c("rgb(205,35,35)"),data=list(-10, -5, -6))    %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Values",color=c("rgb(165,85,85)"),data=list(-2, -5, -3))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="neutral",id='neutral',color=c("#766A62"),data=list(-2, -5, -3))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Valuess",color=c("rgb(35,35,205)"),data=list(5, 1,6))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Valuesss",color=c("rgb(85,85,165)"),data=list(2, 5, 3))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Neutral",linkedTo='neutral',color=c("#766A62"),data=list(6, 8, 2))
```

^Cut and dry for those looking for answer, Special thanks to good ol jbkunst, he made this amazing library and has completely changed the way I present my research( you dah best they evah wuz ;)

I still have the question of how to get the actual values to link together(neutral has a line through it, which is lame.)

Comment: I'm dumb, just add a border width argument and set it to 0 to fuse the neutrals togther.

Comment: is there a way of showing the tooltip and the axis numbers (labels) as absolute values?

Comment: i just found out in here - https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/463 - thanks haha

Answer (score 1):

I'm still fiddling with it but this seems to be closer. I got rid of the colors for now. I was hoping to get the mirrored x-axis but I'll edit that in if I can figure it out. It does show all 3 series though

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "stuff") %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = ""), 
           labels = list(format = "{value}"), min=0) %>% 

  hc_plotOptions(
    series=list(stacking='normal'),
    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE), 
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE) %>% 

  hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(reversed=FALSE,opposite=TRUE,reversed=FALSE, linkedTo=0) %>% 
  hc_add_series(name="Value", data=list(-10, -5, -6)) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="foo",data=list(-2, -15, -3))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="neutral",id='neutral',data=list(-2, -5, -4))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Value",data=list(5, 1, 7))  %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Value", linkedTo = "neutral", data=list(2, 5, 3))
```

Comment: While this is a step in the right direction, I think having a negative side to the scale is part of what makes Likert scales appealing. Otherwise its similar to just a stacking bar chart(useful in certain circumstances).

Comment: I realize such, and the 3rd sentence of my post should reflect that.